# WSO2 IS: How to edit the jsp pages

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have registered applications using OAuth and after registration in the View/Update application settings page we are not able to see the Consumer key and secret. They are hidden fields in the jsp page.

[image]

Now I want to edit the corresponding jsp page in the WSO2 IS to make them visible.
Please suggest me where can I find the corresponding jsp files to edit and after that any deployment or server start up required.

Regards,
Geetha

Comment: Please suggest me is it possible to edit the jsp pages in WSO2 IS and how?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the root directory of the Carbon release you chose, you'll find the .jsp you're looking for in one of the directories with the following format: `components/oauth/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.*/src/main/resources/web/oauth`

where * is variable.